# Maps with multiple types of values java

Tags: java

I need to refactore this code, my problem is a need to use Maps with multiple types of value 
currently I use as a common type an object, 
but I have different types for lists in values.
I do not know how to solve this problem

```
private Map<String, Object> instanceMap(List<String> myList) {

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Product", ListofProduct);
        map.put("Categorie", ListofCategorie);
        map.put("user", ListofUser);

        return map;
}
```

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, you should probably write a class.

Comment: Yes I agree but how to write this class, I am a beginner in java. thank

Comment: How is that code used later? Why are you storing it in Map instead of specified class like `class MyData{ fields holding specific lists, getters/setters etc}`? Why is method argument never used in method body?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this may be a XY problem, where there is a bigger problem you are trying to solve, and might be worth asking that as a question instead.

Storing conflicting types in a collection is a sign you should consider restructuring your code.

One option, mentioned in the comments, is to make a separate class. For example: (in InstanceData.java)

```
public class InstanceData {
    public List<Product> products;
    public List<Category> categories;
    public List<User> users;
}
```

In your method:

```
InstanceData data = new InstanceData();
data.products = ListofProduct;
data.categories = LIstofCategorie;
data.user = ListofUser;
```